# Get value of dynamically chosen class constant in PHP

Tags: php, class-constants

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
class ThingIDs
{
    const Something = 1;
    const AnotherThing = 2;
}

$thing = 'Something';
$id = ThingIDs::$thing;
```

This doesn't work. Is there a straightforward way of doing something equivalent? Note that I'm stuck with the class; it's in a library I can't rewrite. I'm writing code that takes arguments on the command line, and I would *really* like it to take symbolic names instead of id numbers.

Comment: Can you try `ThingIDs::{$thing}`?

Comment: Already tried. Gets me a parse error instead of a fatal runtime error.

Answer (score 233, accepted):

Use the [constant()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) function:

```php
$id = constant("ThingIDs::$thing");
```

Comment: Side note: if you want to first check whether or not the constant is defined, it's `defined("ThingIDs::$thing");`

Comment: or 
$id = constant("self::$thing");

Comment: Similar to this, ```$id = constant(sprintf('%s::%s', ThingIDs::class, $thing));```

Comment: @DavidBaucum why would you wanna over-complicate this? The request is quite simple and involves no outside, user manipulable input. Aside from that, you're calling another function because, I guess, you don't like the string to be concatenated with delimiters?

Comment: Depending on your use-case, my solution is less complicated. Specifically if you are using PSR-4 autoloading, then it can be ugly in your code to have the FQDN spelled out everywhere. By use ```use``` at the top of the file and then using the ```::class``` method to magically get the FQDN improves readability.

Answer (score 32):

Use Reflection

```
$r = new ReflectionClass('ThingIDs');
$id = $r->getConstant($thing);
```

Comment: Reflections really provide a lot of insight into classes, methods and more and it seems a lot of people are afraid to take that step to understand them. Great answer.

Comment: @mikemackintosh
I've taken steps to understand them, but haven't seen much in terms of performance impact vs the accepted answer. THAT is something I'm interested in knowing. Instantiating a new class seems like it'd have a bigger performance hit than simply calling a constant statically.
What are your thoughts on that?

Answer (score 17):

If you are using namespaces, you should include the namespace with the class.

```
echo constant('My\Application\ThingClass::ThingConstant');
```

Answer (score 5):

## Helper function

You can use a function like this:

```
function class_constant($class, $constant)
{
    if ( ! is_string($class)) {
        $class = get_class($class);
    }

    return constant($class . '::' . $constant);
}
```

It takes two arguments:

- Class name or object instance
- Class constant name

If an object instance is passed, its class name is inferred. If you use PHP 7, you can use `::class` to pass appropriate class name without having to think about namespaces.

## Examples

```
class MyClass
{
    const MY_CONSTANT = 'value';
}

class_constant('MyClass', 'MY_CONSTANT'); # 'value'
class_constant(MyClass::class, 'MY_CONSTANT'); # 'value' (PHP 7 only)

$myInstance = new MyClass;
class_constant($myInstance, 'MY_CONSTANT'); # 'value'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

class Dude {
    const TEST = 'howdy';
}

function symbol_to_value($symbol, $class){
    $refl = new ReflectionClass($class);
    $enum = $refl->getConstants();
    return isset($enum[$symbol])?$enum[$symbol]:false;
}

// print 'howdy'
echo symbol_to_value('TEST', 'Dude');
```

Answer (score 1):

With PHP 8.3 you will be able to fetch class constants using variable as the constant name.

```
class A {
  const FOO = 'Test'; 
}
// Usage
$foo = 'FOO';
A::{$foo}; // 'Test'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference to the class itself then you can do the following:

```
if (defined(get_class($course). '::COURSES_PER_INSTANCE')) {
   // class constant is defined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was similiar to this subject. When you have the object, but not the class name, you could use:

```
$class_name = get_class($class_object);
$class_const = 'My_Constant';

$constant_value = constant($class_name.'::'.$class_const);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late, but I hope this can help anyway.

Based on [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil)'s answer, I created a default enumerator class that can be extended.

```
class DefaultEnum
{
    static public function getConstantText(string $constant)
    {
        try {
            // Get child class name that called this method
            $child_class = get_called_class();

            $reflection = new ReflectionClass($child_class);
            $const = $reflection->getConstant($constant);

            return $const;
        } catch (\ReflectionException $e) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}

class CustomEnum extends DefaultEnum
{
    const something = 'abcd';
    const something2 = 'ABCD';
}
```

You can call this method like this

```
CustomEnum::getConstantText('something');
```

It will return `'abcd'`.

The function [`get_called_class()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php) is a function that returns the class name that called this method and it works specifically for static methods.

In this case `$child_class` value will be `CustomEnum::class`. ReflectionClass accepts strings and object as parameter.