# How to access a class const dynamically in PHP?

Tags: php, get, constants

Let's say I have a class like so:

```
class Order {

    const STATUS_INITIALIZED = 'initialized';
    const STATUS_ORDERED = 'ordered';
}
```

and I'd like to grab the constant like so:

```
$status = $_GET['status']; // ?status=STATUS_ORDERED
```

Is there a way to access the value of the constant, given the name of the constant as a string?

I've tried:

```
Order::$status
Order::$$status
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get value of dynamically chosen class constant in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147102/get-value-of-dynamically-chosen-class-constant-in-php)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The function [`constant`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) does this. The syntax is

```
constant('Order::'.$status)
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/cJdZV)**.