# String Resolution Operator to object

Tags: php, scope-resolution-operator

How is it possible to create an object from the following string:

```
$object = 'User::class';
```

Normaly you would remove the quotes but its an dynamic call for example

```
$value = 'User::CONST_NAME_HERE'
function test($value, $delimiter = '::')
{
   list($class, $constant) = explode($delimiter, $value);
   $class = sprintf('%s::class', $class); // not working
}
```

What i'm trying to reach is create a simple function where you could give the classname and the const to get its value.

Comment: Seems to work, maybe make a return statement: return sprintf('%s::class', $class); and call it...

Answer (score 0):

Reference: [Get value of dynamically chosen class constant in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147102/get-value-of-dynamically-chosen-class-constant-in-php)

PHP already has a function which does exactly the same.

```
constant('User::CONST_NAME_HERE')
```

I hope this could help you achieve your goal.