# how to access constant variable of a class using string in phppresentation

Tags: php, phppresentation

[image][image: ][2]]

i want to access const LINE_DOUBLE variable in a class using this "LINE_DOUBLE" string name ANY BEST SOLUTION

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147102/get-value-of-dynamically-chosen-class-constant-in-php

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: PLEASE SEE THE EDITED QUESTION THE METHODS DESCRIBED IN THE LINK YOU SHARED DOESNT SOLVE MY PROBLEM

Comment: @casaca [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)